# High margin of error for circle point calculation

Tags: coordinates, sql-server

Created a circle of points, 50m, 100m, 150m and 200m from a central lat/lng (51.500421, -0.124754) using the sql functions below (one for the lat the other lng). My concern is with the accuracy of the functions. The margin of error for some of the 200m points is near 0.75% (some points being >201.5m from the center point). I run the functions off of a lookup table in sql, which contains rows of the angles I want and the radius. Is there a more accurate equation than the one I have?

[image]

```
Create function [dbo].[NewLatitude] (
    @Latitude float,
    @RadiusKm float,
    @Theta float
)
Returns float as
Begin

Declare @RadiusLon float,
        @RadiusLat float,
        @return_value float;

    Set @RadiusLat =  1 / 110.574 * @RadiusKm
    Set @return_value =  @Latitude + @RadiusLat * sin(@Theta)
 
    Return @return_value
End;
```

```
Create function [dbo].[NewLongitude] (
    @Latitude float,
    @Longitude float,
    @RadiusKm float,
    @Theta float
)
Returns float as
Begin

Declare @RadiusLon float,
        @RadiusLat float,
        @return_value float;

    Set @RadiusLon = (1 / (111.319 * cos(@Latitude * (pi() / 180))) * @radiusKm)
    Set @return_value =  @Longitude + @RadiusLon * cos(@Theta)
 
    Return @return_value
End;
```

Comment: For accurate distances convert your data to a local projected CRS before working on it.

Comment: You really don't want to port the numerical methods solution to the partial differential equation to SQL. You need GIS software in your solution.

Comment: Sadly I can only use SQL in this situation. The longest distance from the point is 200m and I was just hoping I could get the accuracy a bit better over that fairly short distance. Thank you.

Comment: As I'm sure you know, you *could* use the haversine formula or something, and there MAY be a way to get more accuracy by doing a power series approximation (without using the entire haversine formula).

Comment: Thank you. The haversine formula is normally used to find the distance between two points. How would you use it to create a new point? My math is not great. The equation i have is taken from some other code.

Comment: For a given latitude (within the latitude limits permitted by your distance), you can find the longitude of the points that give the desired distance. You should almost certainly find your own implementation, but, if you are completely insane, https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bclib-staging.js#L247 is my implementation

Comment: Ok thank you for that. When you say your own implementation... New to this. Thanks.

Comment: It means how I wrote the function myself. You may want to write it a different way, or find a library that already defines it. It seems like one of those things that's used enough to be in a library, but I haven't really looked.

Comment: Ok thank you for that and your help.